Web page become slower when using order_by in codeignator
I have table consist of around 400K rows and i need to return the data 100 rows for each page. already i used a pagination library in the controller but i faced an issue the model become slower after using order_by to re-sorting the rows as "DESC".
 function fetch_data($limit, $start)
    {
        $this->db->select('pro_id,pro_date,st_target,st_smv,st_name,st_code,pro_account_level,pro_qty,mod_number,modet_desc,a_name,u_name');
        $this->db->from("production_report");
        $this->db->join('stages','stages.st_id = production_report.pro_stage_id');
        $this->db->join('model_details','model_details.modet_id = production_report.pro_model_id');
        $this->db->join('models','models.mod_id = model_details.modet_model_id');
        $this->db->join('accounts','accounts.a_id = production_report.pro_account_id');
        $this->db->join('users','users.u_id = production_report.pro_u_id');
        $this->db->order_by("pro_id", "DESC");
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }  

Adding indexes but nothing changes, when i remove the order_by from the code the page loading faster and normal
enter image description here

What is result from your MySQL Command Prompt for the query  SELECT @@version; ?  Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE "production_report"; ?
